# Insert dotted line in Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I whant to insert a dotted line, in my report, when the text is not present or is blank but I not found information on web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ireport you have an element called line.
You can define it to be dotted with the graphic property pen and with the attribute printWhenExpression you can define when it should be printed. In your case the element would probably look like this in xml:

```
<line>
    <reportElement uuid="da42a40d-89a2-456f-ac44-19c3434c797f" x="59" y="22" width="100" height="1">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{text} == null || $F{text}.isEmpty()]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <graphicElement>
        <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
    </graphicElement>
</line>
```

Comment: I have to set this in every textfield?

Comment: So you want to have a line through a textfield when there is no value?

Comment: Since textfields dont have a property to directly add a line, i think you'd have to add the line on top of the field and only print it when your text is null like shown above.